# WordPress menu with different list style

Tags: wordpress, menu

I would like to list a WordPress menu without list items.

For example:

```
  <div class="nav-start">
  <a class="item">
    Home
  </a>

  <a class="item">
    Menu
  </a>

  <div class="item-with-submenu">

    <a class="parent-link">
      Menu with submenu
    </a>

    <div class="dropdown-child">
      <a class="item">
        Menu
      </a>
      <a class="item">
        Menu
      </a>
      <a class="item">
        Menu
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But it's not working, becasue I can't list the name of parent menu in submenu div, just before the div.

I tried this WordPress function: **wp_get_nav_menu_items()**

Do you have any tip? Thank you!

Comment: What would you consider the name of the parent menu to be? e.g. "Primary Menu"? Do you want to list the name of the parent menu in `<div class="item-with-submenu">` ?

Comment: Yes, in <div class="item-with-submenu">